# Expected number of partitions in Pitman-Yor process

Tags: approximation, gamma-function, pochhammer-symbol

I am reading two articles on this and am trying to reach from the exact formula of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.0296v2) (page 19), to the approximate formula of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.0461v2) (section 3.2). Here are the exact and approximated forms using a unified notation:

Exact: $\mathbb{E}(T) = \frac{\theta}{d}\frac{(\theta+d)_{N}}{(\theta)_{N}}-\frac{\theta}{d}$

Approximation: $\mathbb{E}(T)\approx \frac{\Gamma(1+\theta)}{d\Gamma(d+\theta)}N^d$

In these notations, $N$ is total number of elements (aka number of customers in [Chinese Restaurant Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_restaurant_process) terminology), and $T$ is the total number of partitions (aka number of tables in [Chinese Restaurant Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_restaurant_process) terminology),   $\Gamma$ is the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), $\theta, \alpha$ are the concentration and discount parameters of [Pitman-Yor process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitman%E2%80%93Yor_process), and $(b)_{N}$ is the [pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html) $(b)_{N}=b(b+1)(b+2)...(b+N-1)$.

Comment: Are we allowed to make any assumptions on the relative sizes of the parameters $\theta$, $d$, and $N$?

Comment: Yes, $0\leq d < 1$, and $\theta>-d$, and N is typically $N>>d,\theta$,